# package org.apache.commons.lang does not exist - Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm working on a Spring Boot Project. Everything was okay on yesterday. But today I woke up and open my VScode to remote server to continue my project. I get an error

[image]

In my POM.xml, there's already a dependency,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.11</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also try "mvn install -U". It throws me error,

> package org.apache.commons.lang does not exist

I also searched on the internet, I've found some help from StackOverflow to use a command "mvn dependency:tree" to check there's a dependency exists or not. And here is it !

[image]

I'm stuck for an hour. Please help.

Comment: Is it exist in your .m2 directory?

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed it ! It happened because I remove Eureka Client dependency.
After removing Eureka Client dependency, I need to change

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

to

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;